# How to force text into a specific width?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I use a GridView to display my layout. To this GridView i manually add some RowDefinitions and in this RowDefinitions I add 1 Canvas containing 2 rectangles:

```
 foreach (Method m in sourceFile.getMethods())
            {
                if (!m.getName().StartsWith("<") && !m.getName().EndsWith(">"))
                {
                    RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
                    row.Height = GridLength.Auto;
                    MethodsContainer.RowDefinitions.Add(row);

                    Canvas c = new Canvas();
                    c.Width = width;
                    c.Height = height;
                    c.Tag = m;
                    Contacts.AddPreviewContactDownHandler(c, new ContactEventHandler(onContactDown));

                    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
                    r1.Height = height;
                    r1.Width = m.getLoc() * (width / 1000);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(r1, 0);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(r1, 0);
                    r1.Fill = Brushes.Red;

                    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle();
                    r2.Height = height;
                    r2.Width = width - r1.Width;
                    Canvas.SetTop(r2, 0);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(r2, r1.Width);
                    r2.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

                    c.Children.Add(r1);
                    c.Children.Add(r2);

                    Grid.SetRow(c, rowCounter);
                    MethodsContainer.Children.Add(c);
                    rowCounter++;
                }
            }
```

The canvas is 200px width and 30px height. Both rectangles fill the Canvas exactly. Now i want to add some text over this both Rectangles. But I don't know how long the text is. However I want to force that the text is always printed into this 200px. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could make use of a ViewBox. This will make your text stretch both horizontally and vertically. I assume that's what you want if I understood the question correctly. Example in xaml

```
<Canvas Width="200"
        Height="30">
    <Viewbox Width="200"
             Height="30">
        <TextBlock Text="Text that will fit in 200 Width"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Canvas>
```

And in code behind it will be like

```
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "Text that will fit in 200 Width";

Viewbox viewBox = new Viewbox();
viewBox.Width = width;
viewBox.Height = height;
viewBox.Child = textBlock;

c.Children.Add(viewBox);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var txt = new TextBlock();
txt.MaxWidth = 200;

// optionally you might want the text to wrap if too long
txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
```

By the way, it's **not pixels** in WPF, it's a device-independent unit (1/96th inch) measurement.

Comment: Thanks this is working but it wraps the text in multiple lines. Since i have a fixed height I would prefer if the text just gets smaller.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Did you try my answer? That's pretty much the effect you'll get when using a Viewbox. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Ah i dindt saw it. Thanks. It's exactly what i need.